# Is there a way to identify what component actually allocate memory in a .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I'm developing an application which I would like to be optimized in all aspect and in that objective I would like it not to take too much memory (today it's 145 Mb which for me (51 Years old) is a lot as I used the ZX81 with 1 (one) Kb...)

So is there a way to identify what component actually allocate memory in a .NET app ? I've noticed that RichTextBox with it's undo capacity is a great consumer but is there a way programmatically or with a visual studio (2017 Entreprise) capability, to get a list of allocated memory by "component" or even by variable ? (The memory windows debug seem to be of no help).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like memory leaks hunting. Use memory profiler.

Comment: Thanks but where is the "memory profiler" ?

Comment: @SidiBrah e.g. [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/?fromMenu)

Comment: in Visual Studio, under "Debug" there is a "Show Diagnostic Tools" option  in there, you can get a big tree of items that are allocated but more usefully you can take 'snapshots'.  e.g. run the app, take a snapshot, do something for a short while, take another snapshot and it can compare the two.  Not necessarily the easiest thing to use though, so a profiler as mentioned above may help (not personally used one)

Comment: See [diagnostic tools debugger window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) and [profiling memory usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage). I personally also use dotMemory (albeit rarely).

Comment: I'm 62 and I remember those days as well, and am glad they're gone (for professional work, anyway). If you want that amount of control over the machine then .NET is not a good environment to use; C or C++ is what you're looking for. Rust is also very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 go to the Analyze menu and select "Performance Profiler..." :

[image]

Then choose ".NET Object allocation Tracking", click "Start":

[image]

It will run the application, let it go for a while, then stop it and analyse the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/?gclid=CjwKCAjwpuXpBRAAEiwAyRRPgcyb8I5p5V6l0D4omyOIAKdoqmXKP8w99hgwsRQEa7S2rpiy9iASRhoC2hwQAvD_BwE), it's a great tool for memory leak, memory usage investigation

I also recommend this Microsoft article:

[.NET Memory Allocation Profiling with Visual Studio 2012](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012/)

And this blog post:

[Find, Fix, and Avoid Memory Leaks in C# .NET: 8 Best Practices](https://michaelscodingspot.com/find-fix-and-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c-net-8-best-practices/)

Comment: Here some free alternative of dotMemory: https://alternativeto.net/software/ants-memory-profiler/